# Can Android developers run code before the user launches the application?

Tags: android

Are there valid and deterministic ways to run code between the time a user instals an app and the time they launch the app? The use case is to load config data that is used immediately on app launch (static content from an http request), in this case AB test config data.

Comment: What benefit do you get from that over just loading config data on first launch?

Comment: In my memory, this is a functionality that is **already** banned by Google, but I can't search for it, with keywords like "start app from background before first launch".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen loading time for users. In the context of an AB test setup, if the control group doesn't face a loading penalty and the test group does, it introduces another variable into the experiment beyond the AB test itself.

Comment: @GenoChen I thought so too but couldn't find any references. If such references exist would like to read through them again.

Answer (score 0):

There are some guidelines for Google for this kind of condition. If your app's .apk is beyond 100MB size then Google Play allows you to attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK.

For more details, you can follow [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files) from google.

Let me know if it is helpful for you. 
Thanks,